# calculating array data

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have the following in my db.

Orders:
id: 1
id: 2
id: 3

Order_Items
id: 1, order_id: 1, cost: 10
id: 2, order_id: 1, cost: 15
id: 3, order_id: 2, cost: 5
id: 4, order_id: 2, cost: 60

I then have the following code to output each order and it's total cost:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($orders as $order)
{
    foreach($order->getOrderItems() as $o)
    {
        $total += $o->getCost();
    }

    $content_file .= $total_price . "\r\n";
}
echo $content_file;
```

All works fine, a part from it get the first total `25`, then for the next order, gets the first total and adds it to the 2nd(90) and so on.

Is there anyway I can change my logic to output each order row and the total cost, rather than the addition that is currently going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the $total = 0 line as follows :

```
foreach($orders as $order)
{
    $total = 0;
    foreach($order->getOrderItems() as $o)
    {
        $total += $o->getCost();
    }

    $content_file .= $total . "\r\n";
}
echo $content_file;
```

Comment: What a n00b. Cannot believe i didn't see that. Thanks